# wingpanel disapeared after updating

Tags: updates, wingpanel, appcenter, slingshot

After updating system today my top menu disapeared. The update acted wierd and had issues loading when i tried to run it from app center. I restarted the machine and it resulted in the top menu vanished.

After attempting to fix the problem (by my limited computer skills) here is what came out of my terminal.

sigbjorn@Office:~$ wingpanel &
[1] 3553
sigbjorn@Office:~$
(wingpanel:3553): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 10:58:16.596: Settings schema 'io.elementary.wingpanel.keyboard' is not installed

[1]+  Trace/breakpoint trap   wingpanel
sigbjorn@Office:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install wingpanel
[sudo] password for sigbjorn:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-52-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic but it is not going to be installed or
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-52-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic but it is not going to be installed or
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-53-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-54-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.4.0-54-generic but it is not going to be installed or
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-54-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
sigbjorn@Office:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Answer (score 0):

Seems u got some broken Packages.
Open a terminal and try fixes mentioned [HERE](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/)

When app store is without error and wingpanel is still missing, try:

```
sudo apt-get install wingpanel-indicator-keyboard
```